# How to trim output from a sql query in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, dataframe

I am running sql query from which i am generating output and saving into csv file.

I want to trim output of sql query.

SQL query:

```
"select trim(CONCAT_WS('|','Master Job Name','Seq','TableName','Source File Name Lnd','landingdfname','TargetPath','query1','Execution Sequence')) FROM DUAL"
```

code:

```
with db.cursor() as cur:
    query_meta = ("select trim(CONCAT_WS('|','Master Job Name','Seq','TableName','Source File Name Lnd','landingdfname','TargetPath','query1','Execution Sequence')) FROM DUAL")
    res = cur.execute(query_meta)
    res = cur.fetchall()
```

Getting Output:

```
[{u"trim(CONCAT_WS('|','Master Job Name','Seq','TableName','Source File Name Lnd','landingdfname','TargetPath','query1','Execution Sequence'))": 'Master Job Name|Seq|TableName|Source File Name Lnd|landingdfname|TargetPath|query1|Execution Sequence'}]
```

Desired Output:

```
Master Job Name|Seq|TableName|Source File Name Lnd|landingdfname|TargetPath|query1|Execution Sequence
```

Comment: Hey can you share the output for this: query_meta = "select trim(CONCAT_WS('|','Master Job Name','Seq','TableName','Source File Name Lnd','landingdfname','TargetPath','query1','Execution Sequence')) FROM DUAL". Don't use () around it

Comment: "{u""trim(CONCAT_WS('|','Master Job Name','Seq','TableName','Source File Name Lnd','landingdfname','TargetPath','query1','Execution Sequence'))"": 'Master Job Name|Seq|TableName|Source File Name Lnd|landingdfname|TargetPath|query1|Execution Sequence'}"

Comment: Is it result exactly the same as you have pasted here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean up your results a bit by adding a `as` to your select statement.

```sql
select trim(
  CONCAT_WS(
    '|', 'Master Job Name', 'Seq', 'TableName', 'Source File Name Lnd',
    'landingdfname', 'TargetPath', 'query1', 'Execution Sequence'
  )
) as data FROM DUAL
```

If you use `fetchall()` your result will always be a list.  I am assuming there can be multiple results from this query.

```py
# Your code
with db.cursor() as cur:
    query_meta = ("select trim(CONCAT_WS('|','Master Job Name','Seq','TableName','Source File Name Lnd','landingdfname','TargetPath','query1','Execution Sequence')) FROM DUAL")
    res = cur.execute(query_meta)
    res = cur.fetchall()

# Answer
with db.cursor() as cur:
    query_meta = (
        "select trim(CONCAT_WS("
        "'|','Master Job Name','Seq','TableName','Source File Name Lnd',"
        "'landingdfname','TargetPath','query1','Execution Sequence'"
        ")) as data FROM DUAL")
    res = cur.execute(query_meta)
    res = cur.fetchall()

results = [r["data"] for r in res]

for r in results:
    print(r)
```

Comment: I am doing the same with this query but got some error . Can you please help me?

Comment: query : "SELECT trim(CONCAT_WS('|',mtd.Master_Job_Name,mtd.Seq,mtd.Table_Name,mtd.Source_mtd.File_Name_mtd.Lnd,landingdfname,mtd.Target_Path,mtd.query,mtd.Execution_Sequence )) as data1 from imedical_master_metadata mtd inner join imedical_master_metadata_query mtq on (mtd.Master_Job_Name=mtq.Master_Job_Name) where mtd.Is_Active='Y' order by mtd.Execution_Sequence"

Comment: ERROR : pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.Lnd,landingdfname,mtd.Target_Path,mtd.query,mtd.Execution_Sequence )) as new fr' at line 1")

Comment: i am getting error in above query in as data1 line.

Comment: In the `CONCAT_WS()` You do not have quotes around the expressions.  They appear to be needed.  I had syntax errors until I added them.